# What's the correct way to expose a requireJS module to the global namespace?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to expose a Javascript API as a standalone library without polluting their global namespace. I've created the wrapper so I don't pollute their own requireJS according to http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html. I've simplified what I have so far as below, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way or if I should be doing it some other way.

```
var MyApi = MyApi || {};
var MyApiRequireJS = (function() {
  // require.js pasted here
  return {requirejs: requirejs, require: require, define: define};
})();

(function(require, define, requirejs) {
  require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/scripts',
    waitSeconds: 30,
  });  

  define( 'myapi', ['jquery', 'underscore'],
    function($, _) {
      $.noConflict(true);
      _.noConflict();
      function api(method, args, callback) {
        // do stuff here
      }
      return {api: api};
    }
  );

  require( ['myapi'], function( myapi ) {
    MyApi = myapi;
  });
}(MyApiRequireJS.require, MyApiRequireJS.define, MyApiRequireJS.requirejs));
```

Sites using this library would include a script tag referencing the above code and then call the api using

```
MyApi.api('some_remote_method', {foo: 'bar'}, function(result) {
  // handle the result
});
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't want `require` and `define` to be in the global namespace, but you're happy for `MyApi` and `MyApiRequireJS` to be in the global namespace? Can I ask why?

Comment: It's more likely that they might already be using `require` and `define` than `MyApi` in their global namespace (`MyApi` isn't the var I'm going to use, just used that for simplicity.) Similarly the facebook connect api only pollutes the global namespace with `FB`.

Comment: Are they using `require` or `define`? Can you find out? If not, there isn't a problem. If you don't know what their global namespace uses, then you can't be sure that any globals you define will not already be in use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to anticipate someone else's problem by making it your problem, but I don't think you can really reasonably do that. The page that you link to is designed to let people who already have Javascript globals named "require" or "define" rename the RequireJS globals to something different. It's not intended to create two separate RequireJS instances that independently resolve dependencies.

That said, if you are really trying to minimize the namespace pollution, then you should expose exactly one name -- MyApi. Write one monster closure that includes your private copy of RequireJS as well as your API code, and have it return only the methods you want to expose on your API.

It's probably much friendlier/simpler to deliver your API in two versions, one that defines a requireJS module, and one that has no requireJS dependency.